# Adding pattern data to the collection and copying rows from the collection to different files

Tags: excel, vba

I had the task to extract the table and match the abbreviations in the "Number" column with the list of companies. For example: copy all the rows where "KP00000221" is written in the Number column and put it in a separate file. The same should be done for "VT", "AK" and so on.

[image: file example]

I wrote the code, but I don't have an understanding of how I can create a collection of matches for each abbreviation (there are only five of them). Next, need write collection of rows to different files.

```
Sub testProjectMl()
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("K:K,M:M,N:N").EntireColumn.Delete 'Delete Columns
    
    Set regexPatternOne = New RegExp
    Dim theMatches As Object
    Dim Match As Object
    regexPatternOne.Pattern = "KP\d+|KS\d+|VT\d+|PP\d+|AK\d+" 'Pattern for Search Companies Matches in Range
    regexPatternOne.Global = True
    regexPatternOne.IgnoreCase = True
 
    Dim CopyRng As Range 'Declarate New Range
    
    With Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'because I do not know how many lines there will be in the file
      For i = 8 To LastRow
        'some code
     Next i
    End With
        
        
End Sub
```

As a result, I need to create five different files with tables

[image]

[image]

KP_table -> Paste row with KP00000221

AK_table -> AK data and etc.

The task is complicated by the fact that there can be a lot of such data with abbreviations in the table, and all the row data needs to be filtered and entered into a separate file, where there will be information only on the company. That is, all these abbreviations: KP, KS, AK are different companies.

The problem is that I don't understand how to logically implement the idea: I created a regex pattern, now I need to create a collection (for example, KP_data) and add all the matches for KPXXXXXXXX and so on there.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: When you say "all the rows where "KP00000221" is written" we should understand that there are more occurrences of this  "KP00000221". Is this understanding correct? If yes, you should show us a more relevant picture, containing at least two such cases. Now, do you want copying "the rows" in discussion in consecutive order? Where do you like copying them? Do you need copying the range format, too? Then, `Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)` should be simple `ActiveSheet`...

Comment: Then, your supplied picture is not so appropriate. If I try supplying a piece of code, how can I know where your data is placed on the sheet? You do not show us the rows and columns header...

Comment: @FaneDuru I have added another picture showing the real situation that may be. The first two letters are the name of the order number. There can be five such abbreviations in total: KP, KS, VT, PP, AK. Numbers always follow. I need to determine which company the string belongs to (I do this using regular expressions). That is, there may be five collections in total. Next, insert each collection of rows (if the collection is not empty) into a new file with the abbreviation of the company to which this collection belongs.

Comment: The headers are always located starting from cell A7, followed by the some data.

Comment: You can create a dictionary and assign each unique key (like `KP00000221`) to an exclusive object (like the new worksheet in a new file) so calling something like `dict("KP00000221").Range("A1").Value = something` you can put values in cell A1 from that specific file. After looping trough your data, because headers are always the same, you can insert them in all files looping again through your dictionary

Comment: OK. I already prepared a piece of code (with a configurable headers row). Now, I would like to know where to return the data. I will try returning in the next sheet... Setting the sheet where to be returned is easy to be done, I think.

Comment: Please, test the code I posted. Also take care to have (insert) an empty sheet **after the one to be processed**. There the code will return the processing result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It uses a dictionary to keep a `Union` range of each case and drop each its item in the next sheet, with an empty row between them. Copying a `Union` range instead of each involved row, is much faster:

```
Sub testProjectMl()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long, lastERowDest As Long
 Dim i As Long, arrA, dict As Object
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 firstRow = 7 'the row where the headers exist
 
 Set shDest = sh.Next
 
 arrA = sh.Range("A" & firstRow & ":A" & lastRow).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 
 For i = 2 To UBound(arrA) 'iterate between the array rows
    If Not dict.Exists(arrA(i, 1)) Then 'if not a key exists:
        'create it composed by the header and the current row
        dict.Add arrA(i, 1), Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                               sh.Range(sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
    Else 
        'make a Union between the existing item and the new row:
        Set dict(arrA(i, 1)) = Union(dict(arrA(i, 1)), _
                 sh.Range(sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
    End If
 Next i
 'drop the dictionary items content (in the next sheet) with an empty row between each group:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    lastERowDest = shDest.Range("A" & shDest.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    If lastERowDest = 2 Then lastERowDest = 1
    dict.items()(i).Copy shDest.Range("A" & lastERowDest + 1)
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I get error "Object Variable or With block variable not set" at 
>lastERowDest = shDest.Range("A" & shDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: Is there a sheet after the active one, as stated in my comment?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Everything works, thank you.

Comment: @Foertsch Is it in the above code something making you fill that it did not answer your question? I aske "Where do you like copying them?", but no answer from your side... The above code can be easily adapted to return in a new workbook, adding as many sheets as companies exist and drop in each of them the appropriate specific content. Or in a different way. I would like to specify that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your code helped me. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize for the impudence. But I have a question: can I, in the Union method when combining range, specify the strings that were previously declared in my code? Example: "dict.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")), string1, string2)". Or does this method allow to combine only ranges? Thank you.

Comment: `Union` means a union of **ranges**... But a dictionary accepts all sorts of variables. In your case you may load it with an array having its first element the `Union` range and second one an array of strings. Something like `dict.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Array(Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow), sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")), Array( string1, string2))`...

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim Dict As Object
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim MyKey As Object

Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim LR2 As Long
Dim WKdata As Worksheet

Set WKdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data") 'Worksheet with source data

With WKdata
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data
End With

For i = 8 To LR Step 1 '8 is first row with data, headers are in row 7

    If Dict.Exists(WKdata.Range("A" & i).Value) = False Then
        'This number is first time found. Create file and add it
        Workbooks.Add 'now this is the activeworkbook
        Dict.Add WKdata.Range("A" & i).Value, ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'create a reference for this file
        WKdata.Range("A7:K7").Copy Dict(WKdata.Range("A" & i).Value).Range("A1:K1") 'headers from row 7
        WKdata.Range("A" & i & ":K" & i).Copy Dict(WKdata.Range("A" & i).Value).Range("A2:K2") 'row 2 is always first row of data
    Else
        'this number has been found before. Add data to existing file
        With Dict(WKdata.Range("A" & i).Value)
            LR2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '1 row below last row with data
        End With
        WKdata.Range("A" & i & ":K" & i).Copy Dict(WKdata.Range("A" & i).Value).Range("A" & LR2 & ":K" & LR2)
    End If
Next i

Set Dict = Nothing
Set WKdata = Nothing


End Sub
```

The code loops trough a dictionary with references to each new file created.

My source data is a worksheet named `Data`

[image]

After executing code, I get new files for each key (grouped rows by keys)

[image]

As you can see, I got 3 different unique keys and each one to their file with all its data.

You only need to adapt the code to save each file where you want, following your pattern. Probably you'll need to loop trough each key of the dictionary, check number value and then save the file properly

About dictionaries in VBA, please check this source:

> [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete
> Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)